# Add new disk to an available zpool

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zpool

A zpool is created with name tank. By using zfs command, a disk is added to the pool. Now the disk contains data which is not going to be lost. I buy a new disk and want to append it to the same pool to increase its space dynamically. The new disk size may be different. Indeed I need a linear mode raid on the fly.

Is it possible? If yes, How? If not, what's the best replacement in such a case?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [take the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how Super User works. Read [how to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.